# How to register a global directive in Vue for entire app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i register a Vue directive so it's available in all of my components of my Vue application? I'm using Vue 2

The docs say you can register global but where in my project do I add this `Vue.directive(....)`

**src/directives/TestMe.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.directive('test-me', {
  inserted(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  },
})
```

src/components/SignInForm.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <code v-test-me>
            Hello World
        </code>
    </div>

</template>

</script>
```

I know the current way of doing this by doing the following. However it's not practical if I plan on using my directive in multiple components and pages of my application.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <code v-test-me>
            Hello World
        </code>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestMe from '../../directives/TestMe'
export default {
    directives: {
        TestMe
    }
}
</script>
```

**Updated**
Updated post based on answers below.

I've created a different files for each directive and then have an index.js file where i import all my directives. How can i initiate that index.js file in the directives folder at the start of my application?

```
// src/directives/TestMe.js
export default testMe = {
  inserted(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  },
}

// src/directives/index.js
import testMe from './TestMe'

export default {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.directive('test-me', testMe)
    // Vue.directive('other-directive', myOtherDirective)
  },
}

// src/main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import ???? from './directives'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(????)
```

You have globalDirectives...where does that name come from?

Comment: globalDirectives is just a variable name, you can just put anything there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: I didn't read that OP is using Vue 2.

To call `.use()`, you need to export object with function
`install(Vue)`

If you want the directive as a separate file.

```js
// src/directives/TestMe.js

const testMe = {
  inserted(el) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  },
}
export default testMe
```

Here is where you register all the directives. You can import files or just define your directives here.

```js
// src/directives/index.js

import testMe from './TestMe'

// const myOtherDirective = {
//   ...
// }

export default {
  install (Vue) {
    Vue.directive('test-me', testMe)
    // Vue.directive('other-directive', myOtherDirective)
  }
}
```

## Here is how to register directives in Vue 2

You can register the global directives in main.js with Vue.use

```js
// src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import globalDirectives from './directives'
Vue.use(globalDirectives)

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
app.$mount('#app')
```

## Here is how to register directives in Vue 3

You can register the global directives in main.js after createApp

```js
// src/main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import globalDirectives from './directives'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(globalDirectives)
```

Comment: That's great thank you so much for showing solutions for both vue 2 and vue 3.

Comment: what would be in the contents of the globalDirectives file? just a file that does all the imports?

Comment: @JokerMartini globalDirectives imports file from /src/directives/index.js
See the first snippet. You can define all your directive there, or import from separate files and register them with Vue.directive(). Wait, I'll add the snippet to register directive from separate file.

Comment: Ok great, ive done what you've said. I've updated the original post to show you. Not sure how to import the index.js into the main.js file to init the directives...?

Comment: @JokerMartini he does it right here `import globalDirectives from './directives'` index.js is imported by default if you leave it out.